# OSB Proxy Service message processing

Tags: jms, weblogic, osb

In Weblogic OSB, we have a Proxy Service which is simply supposed to consume messages from a remote Weblogic JMS Queue and route them to another remote Weblogic JMS Queue via a Business Service. For some reason, messages get consumed by the Proxy Service but, they never get routed to the Business Service.

Current behaviour:

When enabled, OSB Proxy Service removes any messages placed in the remote endpoint URI queue, but messages seem to not flow within the Proxy Service's message flow itself. When the Proxy Service is enabled, the messages in the remote queue get removed but are seen to stay in a 'pending' state. When the Proxy Service is disabled, the messages get put back in the queue.

What are the possible reasons as to why messages would not get processed within the Proxy Service's message flow? All the message flow does is, route the messages to a Business service which then sends the messages to another remote endpoint URI queue.

PS: When a message is injected into the Proxy Service via the Test Console, the message flows/routes to Business Service okay without problems so I assume that the problem must lie in the initial remote queue/Proxy Service interface somewhere? Maybe permissions or transaction related issue? But I can't see any hints to anything wrong in configurations or server(s) logs...

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: In the OSB console go to the proxy in question, click the Operational Settings tab and turn on the tracing options. Maybe that will help you get some logging to determine what's happening? You can do that for the business service as well.

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp, thanks for the suggestion. I do believe that I have tracing enabled already and yet, I don't see anything logged when the Proxy Service is enabled and removes a message from the remote queue. Am I right to think that trace logs should get written to the OSB server's standard log file? Or am I looking for traces in the wrong place?

Comment: You should be able to tail the log for the managed server whose proxy you are hitting and see messages like: "[OSB Tracing] Routing to /services/enterprise/DataService/v2.0.0/DataServiceBusiness with message context:" and then later "[OSB Tracing] The following variables are changed:" or "[OSB Tracing] Inbound response was sent" Make sure it's the managed server log and not a different one. Something like <domain home>/servers/<managed server name>/logs

Comment: I have looked in the OSB server's log files and there is no sign of any Trace level messages being logged. When I enable the Proxy Service I can see an INFO level log which shows: `The Message-Driven EJB has connected/reconnected to the JMS destination: REMOTE_QUEUE_NAME` and I can see the remote queue's `Messages Current` count go down to 0 and the `Messages Pending` count increase to 1, but no traces of anything going through the Proxy Service appear in the log files.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I'm currently having the same issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BrunoGasparotto, it was a long time ago now but from what I remember we had to resort to restarting the server itself to get the proxy service processing messages again.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and discovered that it might be a naming conflict issue.

If you have repeated names for your resources regardless in which server they are, WebLogic is likely to produce unexpected behaviour. So according to Oracle's document [Best Practices for JMS Beginners and Advanced Users](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13738/best_practice.htm#JMSAD635), you should adhere to the following naming rules:

> - Domain names must be unique.
> - WebLogic server names must be unique, even if they are in two different domains.
> - JMS server names must be unique, even if they are in two different domains.

To exemplify a scenario issuing the above statements. I had the following problematic topology:

```
|   WebLogic    |   IP          |   Domain      |   Server      |
|   WebLogic 1  |   10.10.10.73 |   osb_domain  |   osb_server1 |
|   WebLogic 2  |   10.10.10.83 |   osb_domain  |   osb_server1 |
|   WebLogic 3  |   10.10.10.93 |   osb_domain  |   osb_server1 |
```

Notice the name clash between the domains and servers. Even if I had different names for my JMS resources, these naming conflicts were enough to cause problems.

Then I changed my topology to the following:

```
|   WebLogic    |   IP          |   Domain      |   Server      |
|   WebLogic 1  |   10.10.10.73 |   osb_domain1 |   osb_server1 |
|   WebLogic 2  |   10.10.10.83 |   osb_domain2 |   osb_server2 |
|   WebLogic 3  |   10.10.10.93 |   osb_domain3 |   osb_server3 |
```

No more conflicts this time then my JMS queues started to work as expected, without any modification on the previous code for my proxy and business services.

Comment: naming conflict issues could well have been a problem accross Weblogic domains in the original question's setup. I can't say for sure that was the issue now but your comment can helpfully help others in future.

Answer (score 0):

In your Proxy service, go to Operation settings tab and make sure you have the logging enabled to Debug with tracing enabled. Tracing should be set to Full and size as 800.

Regards
Syed K

Answer (score -1):

you can set the "MAx Messages Per Session" property of the JMS Connection Factory: the default is 10, set it to 1 to have only 1 JMS message delivered to each consumer at a time. The default behaviour is that up to 10 messages are delivered to the same consumer, which has only 1 Thread, so all 10 are marked as Pending while 1 only is being processed.